# How to fix Andersen storm door that's leaning and dragging?

Tags: doors, hinges, storm-door

Images: https://imgur.com/a/x8YLwiV

I have an Andersen storm door. The serial number is included in the image[1] above.

The metal frame itself is level and aligned with the doorframe. However, the actual door sags noticeably on the latch side away from the hinges (see image [2]). This results in rubbing on the threshold, which is wearing unevenly (see image [3]) and makes it difficult to close.

I've noticed if I lift it up a little on its hinges it lines up. It seems the door is pulling down vertically on the hinges because it's starting to actually grind away at the bottom of each hinge (see images [4][5][6][7].)

Most guidance I can find online for fixing a sagging storm door is about re-nailing the frame, but that doesn't seem like my issue?

Any help or guidance is appreciated!

[1] https://imgur.com/3Si8UNm

[2] https://imgur.com/uRARPQo

[3] https://imgur.com/Nsbo2XE

[4] https://imgur.com/87mhdh4

[5] https://imgur.com/PqviVf3

[6] https://imgur.com/tdFJPYR

[7] https://imgur.com/Vjc4cru

Comment: The hinge screws are probably loose.  Tighten them up or replace with longer screws.  If the screws go into wood, then the holes might be stripped and will need to either use toothpicks and glue to fill the screw holes or drill the holes out to fit in a wood dowel and then rescrew.